# List of records for youngest female grandmasters since 1950?

Tags: history, statistics, records, titles, women

On Wiki, we have a list for [List of youngest grandmasters since 1950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_prodigy#List_of_youngest_grandmasters).

1. What about female GMs (really female GMs and [not WGMs](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37149/list-of-records-for-youngest-wgms-woman-grandmasters-since-1950)) instead of GMs?

I guess the list ends with Judit Polgar, Koneru Humpy and Hou Yifan.

> In 2002, she became the youngest woman ever to achieve the title of Grandmaster at the age of 15 years, 1 month, 27 days, beating Judit Polgár's previous record by three months[2](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37149/list-of-records-for-youngest-wgms-woman-grandmasters-since-1950) (this record was subsequently broken by Hou Yifan in 2008).

2. Btw, if I ask for the list of youngest females to reach 2500+ then is it the same thing as this? I was thinking maybe not because I guess you could reach 2500+ without having the GM norm. [List of records for youngest superWGMs since 1950?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36892/list-of-youngest-superwgms-since-1950)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wait it's on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_female_chess_players) because 'age' is 'age obtained' (duh!). Ok so the list just goes

1. Nona Gaprindashvili - 37
2. Maia Chiburdanidze - 23
3. Susan Polgár - 22 (Note: Susan Polgár became GM in Jan1991 while Judit Polgár became GM in Dec1991.)
4. Judit Polgár - 15 (15 years and 4 months)
5. Humpy Koneru - 15 (15 years, 1 month, 27 days)
6. Hou Yifan - 14

Bonus: If we exclude Judit Polgár and Humpy Koneru:

1. Nona Gaprindashvili - 37
2. Maia Chiburdanidze - 23
3. Susan Polgár - 22
4. Alexandra Kosteniuk - 20
5. Kateryna Lahno - 17
6. Hou Yifan - 14

Comment: What value does the second list add? Why aren't Kosteniuk and Lagno on the first list? What possible rationale could there be to 'exclude Judit Polgár and Humpy Koneru'?

Comment: @MobeusZoom same as this: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36909/list-of-records-for-youngest-female-international-masters-since-1950

Comment: Ah I understand. But the choice is still odd and should be more clearly explained. (Your motive is obviously to pigeonhole in the information about Kosteniuk and Lagno - which is fine but make it clearer what's happening and why!) BrianTowers' rationale behind excluding Judit Polgar was to provide a meaningful list beyond just 'Polgar held the record since 1988 and no-one came close afterwards'. Removing Polgar and Humpy's GM titles is less coherent, as they are less exceptional, i.e. you could do the same with pretty much any of your 'youngest' questions.