# List of records for youngest superWGMs since 1950?

Tags: history, statistics, records, titles, women

On Wiki, we have a list for [List of youngest grandmasters since 1950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_prodigy#List_of_youngest_grandmasters). What about superWGMs (any female player who has reached [2500+](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating) or has become GM, whether or not they were actual WGMs so as to include Judit Polgar) instead of GMs?

Note 1: I use 2500 as the mark for superWGM based on [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34935/why-do-women-have-a-lower-elo-requirement-to-obtaining-women-fide-titles) and [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating).

Note 2: I'm guessing this is a different question from this ([List of records for youngest female grandmasters since 1950?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/list-of-youngest-female-grandmasters-since-1950)) because you could reach [2500+](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating) without getting the norms right? But eh it's probably the same answer anyway.

Comment: Have you considered purchasing the Chessbase MegaDatabase? Might answer all these questions. Also SuperWGM isn't a sanctioned term by Fide (Just like SuperGM isn't).

Comment: Unfortunately i don't think these are statistics that being well tracked in general (which is a bit pathetic imo). From what i can see the youngest rated female to hit a FIDE rating of 2500 would Aleksandra Goryachkina, unforunately ELO profiles are not necessarily available for all female chess players so it cannot be objectively achieved

Comment: What about trying to group all these questions in a couple of (ehem) questions: [you're populating SE's chess](https://imgur.com/a/w3Wpoz7), and it's starting to become annoying. If I had the option to block some user's questions I wouldn't make this comment, but that doesn't seem to be SE's politics: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277425/how-can-i-block-a-user

Comment: @DavidBateman never mind. figured it out. posted answer. thanks anyway.

Comment: @emdio 'I don't think the situation will be improved by combining them all into a single question, but you might want to bring it up on Chess Meta so that we (the entire community) can come to a consensus. – 
Glorfindel♦
 Sep 8 at 7:51 ' https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36909/list-of-records-for-youngest-female-international-masters-since-1950#comment59550_36909 also: never mind. figured it out. posted answer. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah here: the ff have reached 2500+ according to [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36698/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating-with-countries) but aren't GM:

1. Lela Javakhishvili
2. Almira Skripchenko
3. Qin Kanying
4. Svetlana Matveeva
5. Polina Shuvalova

Since all the peaks are 2500-2502, I'm just gonna assume the time they got the peaks is the 1st time they got the peaks sooo...

1. Lela Javakhishvili - 2500 in March 2010 at the age of 25
2. Almira Skripchenko - 2501 in January 2003 at the age of 26
3. Qin Kanying - 2501 in July 2000 at the age of 26
4. Svetlana Matveeva - 2502 in January 2004 at the age of 34
5. Polina Shuvalova - [2507 in August 2021 at the age of 20](https://www.chessgraphs.com/?name%5B0%5D=Shuvalova%2C%20Polina&name%5B1%5D=&format=fide-standard)

These are all over 15 years of age and all after Judit Polgar became GM (and thus superWGM).

**Conclusion**: The superWGM list is, for now, **the same** as the [female GM](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/list-of-records-for-youngest-female-grandmasters-since-1950) list.

---

**Update**: Ok so there are also females who obtained GM without reaching 2500+ like Peng Zhaoqin. I don't think this affects either the superWGM list or the female GM list. If anyone has any idea, then please let me know.